# How to check the value a property of items from the Firebase database before deleting items

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Firebase Data Model:

```
Database:
    tweets
         favorite:Bool
         tweetText: String
         userID: String
         timestamp: Double
```

I want to run a method that says "delete tweets, that aren't favorited, within the last 2 hours"

Here's what I have in the console (//'s are where I need help):

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const admin = require('firebase-admin')

admin.initializeApp();

exports.deleteOldItems = functions.database.ref(‘/tweets/{tweet}’)
.onWrite((change, context) => {
         var ref = change.after.ref.parent; 
         var now = Date.now();
         var cutoff = now - 2 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
         var oldItemsQuery = ref.orderByChild('timestamp').endAt(cutoff);
         return oldItemsQuery.once('value', function(snapshot) {

                                   var updates = {};
                                   snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
                    // Delete Tweet BUT ONLY IF FAVORITE == True????
                    //Help here
                                                    updates[child.key] = null
                                                    });
                                   // execute all updates in one go and return the result to end the function
                                   return ref.update(updates);
                                   });
         });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for something like this:

```
exports.deleteOldItems = functions.database.ref(‘/tweets/{tweet}’)
  .onWrite((change, context) => {
     var ref = change.after.ref.parent; 
     var now = Date.now();
     var cutoff = now - 2 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
     var oldItemsQuery = ref.orderByChild('timestamp').endAt(cutoff);
     return oldItemsQuery.once('value', function(snapshot) {
           var updates = {};
           snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
               if (!child.val().favorite) {
                    updates[child.key] = null
               }
           });
           // execute all updates in one go and return the result to end the function
           return ref.update(updates);
           });
     });
})
```

If you are new to (using Firebase from) JavaScript, Cloud Functions for Firebase is not the easiest way to learn it. I recommend first reading the [Firebase documentation for Web developers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start) and/or taking the [Firebase codelab for Web developer](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/). They cover many basic JavaScript, Web and Firebase interactions. You could also use the Admin SDK in a local Node.js process, which can be debugged with a local debugger. After those you'll be much better equipped to write code for Cloud Functions too.

Comment: Thanks Frank! I was struggling with the Cloud Functions interface.

Comment: The bit I added in my answer (`if (!child.val().favorite) {`) has nothing to do with Cloud Functions, hence my recommendation to learn about it in environment that lends itself more to fast iterative experimentation.